# Incorrect syntax near '?' when inserting data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, go

I got the status "add successfully" but the data is not inserted to my sql database. However, the data is inserted to SQL database if it is hardcoded. I am wondering the problem arises due to the sql query. I got the Error mssql: Incorrect syntax near '?'.

```
type CreateAccount struct {
    AccountPassword string `json:"accountPassword" binding:"required"`
    UserName string `json:"userName" binding:"required"`
}

// SignUp takes a user JSON and stores in DB.
// SignUp             godoc
// @Summary      Create a new user
// @Description  Takes an account JSON and stores it in DB. Return saved JSON.
// @Tags         User
// @Produce      json
// @Param        account  body      models.Account  true  "Account JSON"
// @Success      200   {object}  models.Account
// @Router       /users [post]
func SignUp(c *gin.Context) {

    if db.InitialConnection() != nil {//connection to database
        var dtTable = db.InitialConnection() 
        var newUser CreateAccount

        var err error
        var res sql.Result
        _ = err
        _ = res

        // Call BindJSON to bind the received JSON to new user
        if err := c.BindJSON(&newUser); err != nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, "fail to parse json ")

        }
        account := models.Account{ //imported Account struct from package models
            AccountPassword: newUser.AccountPassword,
            UserName:        newUser.UserName,
        }
        res, err = dtTable.Exec("INSERT INTO Account(accountPassword, userName) VALUES(?, ?)", account.AccountPassword, account.UserName) // insert into sql databas

        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, "add sucess")

    } else {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, "first initial connection failed ")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Did you check the error from `dtTable.Exec` ?

Comment: Error: mssql: Incorrect syntax near '?'. I got this error but I have no idea what is the syntax problem

Comment: What that "SQL database" really is? What engine? And please, please do the usual engineering practice and narrow the problem down: the fact the code is running in a server which accepts HTTP requests, and handling of those requests has absolutely, zero, relation to the problem. Make a simple command-line program which does nothing beyond inserting records to a DB table and debug _it._

Comment: OK, I see it's "mssql". So, let's make the next step: are you using `database/sql`? If yes, which driver package are you using with it to make it access an MSSQL-hosted database?

Comment: Yes, I am using database/sql.  This is the driver package I use: "github.com/microsoft/go-mssqldb"

Comment: OK, so scroll the documentation down to the "Parameters" section: <https://github.com/microsoft/go-mssqldb#parameters>. I mean, what you're dealing with here is called "parameterized query". Some SQL-related packages for Go which work atop `database/sql` (such as `sqlx`) have their own knowledge about peculiarities of particular SQL DB engines, but `database/sql` does not hide such differences, and you have been tripped by this. I think you might want to read up on T-SQL (which is an MSSQL-specific SQL dialect).

Comment: A couple of suggestions while'we are at it: 1) Never, never ignore errors. In production code, properly thought-out handling of errors is no less important that handling the "normal" flow; I personally lean that properly handling corner-cases is of more importance, even. 2) Consider adding context to your errors which helps debugging big time: when you fail to parse JSON, don't _replace_ the original error with a useless "failed to parse json" text; include the original error's text as well (for a Internet-facing service this might have further security considerations though). …

Comment: … Always try to decompose problems. When you have a web server which ostensibly inserts some data to a table hosted by a DB engine, the problem is almost certainly not in the web-serving code—as long as that code had surely handled your request. Please ponder this carefully.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like your passwords are being stored as clear text. They need to be salted and hashed. Anything less is borderline criminal mishandling of sensitive data.